# ACE Driver Works in VBA but not C# - Why?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, ms-jet-ace

I want to know why the ACE Driver works in VBA when I want to read an Excel (VBA) file but fails when I try it in Visual Studio Code (C#).

I know that you need to install the Access Runtime to get the ACE Drivers, but this is not possible without Admin rights. I also know that you can use the Interop to read Excel files with C#. I just want to understand why the basically same code in VBA works but doesn't work in C#.

This works in VBA:

```
connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= " & filePath & _
      "; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';"
    connection.Open connString
```

But this fails in C#:

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + @";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;'";  
using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
   connection.Open();
}
```

When I run the C# I get the The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine error'

I have dealt with this issue before, but would love someone who understands it better to help out. Is it the ActiveX reference in Excel? Can I someone access this without using the Interop?

Comment: They're not the same though. VBA has `;` outside the single quotes, C# has them inside. Does it work if you remove the `Extended Properties`?

Comment: The oiedb ACE driver for c# and excel are the same.  ACE is part of Microsoft Office and will be automatically registers when office is installed.  Office requires a license, but it is possible to install Ace without the license.  If VBA works and c# doesn't work then I suspect VBA is using a 32 bit ACE dll while Net is using a 64 bit ACE dll.

Comment: Are you using Office365? If so, that's a problem because the components are sandboxed and thus not available to non-Office-VBA consumers like C# or anyone else. You do need to install Access redistributable for those scenarios.